# Field renormalization in 4D $\phi^4$ theory from sunset diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

Consider the contribution to the two-point function in (euclidean) 4D $\phi^4$ theory, given by the sunset diagram. It is proportional to:
$$
\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{1}{(k^2+m^2)(q^2+m^2)((k+q-p)^2 + m^2)}
$$
where $p$ is an external momentum and some regularization is implied, for the following steps to make sense. We expect that the divergent part of this diagram can be cancelled with counterterms for kinetic and mass term, namely, it has the form $A + B p^2$. Let us try extracting the divergent coefficient $B$ before $p^2$ by differentiating the integral twice with respect to $p_\mu$ and then putting $p^2=0$. We have
$$
\frac{d}{dp_\mu} \frac{1}{(p-k-q)^2 + m^2} = - \frac{2(p-k-q)^\mu}{((p-k-q)^2+m^2)^2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dp^\mu}\left(- \frac{2(p-k-q)^\mu}{((p-k-q)^2+m^2)^2} \right)= \frac{-8}{((p-k-q)^2 +m^2)^2} + \frac{8 (p-k-q)^\mu (p-k-q)_\mu}{((p-k-q)^2 +m^2)^3}
$$
Putting $p=0$, the integral we need to calculate $B$ reduces to
\begin{align}
&8\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{1}{(k^2+m^2)(q^2+m^2)}\left[\frac{-1}{((k+q)^2 +m^2)^2} + \frac{(k+q)^2}{((k+q)^2 +m^2)^3}\right] = \\
&= 8\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{1}{(k^2+m^2)(q^2+m^2)} \frac{m^2}{((k+q)^2 + m^2)^3}
\end{align}
But this integral is convergent, although from other calculations we expect this diagram to yield a divergent contribution to field renormalization to this order in coupling constant.
What goes wrong in the argument above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the final integral is still divergent. Consider the integral over $q$. It is no less than the integral over $q$ over a ball of radius order 1 centered at $-k$, which in turn is around $k^{-4}$ at large $k$. Therefore the $k$ integral is logarithmically UV divergent, as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I expected the integral to converge, since one can proceed with the usual introduction of Feynman parameters and making the integral spherically symmetric in 8d space of the form d8k/k^10, which would be UV-finite. Could you perhaps comment on what happens in this case? Does the divergence move to the integral over Feynman parameters?

Comment: @AleksandrArtemev to make it spherically symmetric you'll need to bring a quadratic form to a canonical form, with original eigenvalues that depend on Feynman parameters. I think you'll get a divergence from the values of the parameters where that form becomes degenerate, but I'm not sure.